# What is the most succinct way to use '!=' operator when comparing multiple values to the same variable?

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators

**EDIT:** 
I did not mean efficiency as in the program running more efficiently, but I meant it as a quicker way to program the if statement.

I am trying to find a way to reduce my code for efficiency.
For example: `if(x!=10 && x!=20 && x!=30){}` //etc`
I tried this, and I tried multiple other methods:

```
if(x!=(10 && 20 && 30){}
```

It does not work. Is there a way to reduce the size of this if statement?

Comment: Put the values in an array, use a for loop.  The `if` statement will be small because you are compare the variable to an array slot.

Comment: If you are looking for efficiency, i guarantee you are barking up the wrong tree. There is no way this will be the place that is slowing down your code. Profile first.

Comment: Did you try a profiler before? Maybe you're trying to optimize something that does not affect the performance...

Comment: You could use parenthesis to group the expressions, then place one expression per line.

Comment: Just to explain why the second one doesn't work, you are ANDing the boolean values of 10,20, and 30 together, so true&true&true which is true, and then checking if x doesn't equal that.

Comment: You are trying to micro-optimize things that the compilers optimizer has probably already done a great job with. In any case, except for rare cases in very hot paths, trivial stuff like this is very unlikely to have any measurable impact; don't waste your time with it.

Comment: I did not mean efficiency as in the program running more efficiently, but I meant it as a quicker way to program the if statement. Thanks, sorry for confusion and not being specific enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a `switch`:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 10:
    case 20:
    case 30:
        break;
    default:
        // do something ...
        break;
}
```

Another way is to use an array (or equivilent STL container, like `std::vector` or `std::array`):

```
#include <algorithm>

const int okValues[] = {10, 20, 30};
const int *end = &okValues[3];

if (std::find(okValues, end, x) == end)
{
    // do something ...
}
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> okValues;
okValues.push_back(10);
okValues.push_back(20);
okValues.push_back(30);

/* or, in C++11 and later:
std::vector<int> okValues {10, 20, 30};
*/

if (std::find(okValues.begin(), okValues.end(), x) == okValues.end())
{
    // do something ...
}
```

```
// C++11 and later only...

#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

std::array<int, 3> okValues = {10, 20, 30};

if (std::find(okValues.cbegin(), okValues.cend(), x) == okValues.cend())
{
    // do something ...
}
```

Another way is to use a `std::set`:

```
#include <set>

const int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
const std::set<int> okValues(arr, arr+3);

/* or, in C++11 and later:
const std::set<int> okValues {10, 20, 30};
*/

if (okValues.find(x) == okValues.end()) // or cend() in C++11 and later
{
    // do something ...
}
```

Or, in the very specific case of your particular 3 example values:

```
int result = x / 10;
int remainder = x % 10;

if ((result < 1) || (result > 3) || (remainder != 0))
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: This is a different way, but isnt any more efficient in code length or performance?

Comment: Can you please explain by which definition the switch solution is more efficient?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: depending on optimizations, rather than invoking multiple `if` statements, the compiler may be able to analyze the `switch` cases and create more efficient jump tables, allowing a given input value to jump directly to the `default` code without having to evaluate the other values.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux   The `switch` statement reduces the `if` statement, which is one of your requirements.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have a link to the compiler flag for gcc or something that does this optimization?

Comment: std::none_of / any_of is a tiny bit simpler and more self-explanatory than fiind.,,

Comment: @TonyD: not quite. `std::any_of()`/`std::none_of()` don't take a specific search value as input, only a predicate (like a lambda). And they are new in C++11, whereas `find()` works in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to reduce the size of this if statement? ...  not mean efficiency as in the program running more efficiently, but ... quicker way to program the if statement.

I'll take this to mean that you want fewer characters than `if (x!=10 && x!=20 && x!=30)` and/or "easier" typing rather than code than runs faster.

One way, similar to Remy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493317/8877), use a `set`.  With a utility routine like:

```
bool in(int x, const std::initializer_list<int>& values)
{
    const std::set<int> s{ values };
    return s.find(x) != s.cend();
}
```

your `if` statement is now `if (!in(x, { 10, 20, 30 }))`.  That (barely) reduces the overall character count and it might be slightly easier to type than `!=` and `&&` multiple times.

Rather than an `in()` function, you could overload an operator like `!=`:

```
bool operator !=(int x, const std::set<int>& s) {
    return s.find(x) == s.cend();
}
```

and then use it

```
using si = std::set<int>; // si == set<int>
if (x != si{ 10, 20, 30 } ) { }
```

ignoring the `using`, this is fairly succinct and matches the `!=` syntax.  Note that your fellow developers may not like this, as it would be a somewhat unusual idiom compared to the "normal" way (which you want to avoid).